# Rating stars crashing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, comments, prestashop-1.6, rating, review

I have issue with product comments in Prestashop 1.6.1.1 (default Bootstrap theme).

When I want to add review, and modal appears, the stars selecting is broken:
[here is link to picture](http://oi60.tinypic.com/260eazs.jpg)
(*sorry for link, but I haven't reputation to post images, yet*)

I have no idea, why it is crashing.

I think it isn't possible to add code of that module in jsfiddle or others, so i add link to my test page of prestashop:
[link to page](http://firmaskiba.lh.pl/ps/)
On the page is only one product, try to preview them and add opinion/review.

Have someone any idea?

P.S. Sorry for maybe poor English..

Comment: did you change something in *productcomments* module code? by default all works fine

Comment: I did't change it. Only I make translation from English to Polish, but it only by Presta Admin Panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, possible to fix by two ways:

1. use theme from 1.6.0.11 version

or

2. in themes/default-bootstrap/js/global.js find lines:

`if (typeof bindUniform !=='undefined')
bindUniform();`

and comment it:

`// if (typeof bindUniform !=='undefined')
// bindUniform();`

from [here](http://forge.prestashop.com/browse/PSCSX-6504)